# How to install php5-phpdbg in Trusty (14.04)?

Tags: 14.04, apt, php

The package php5-phpdbg is not included in the universal repository of trusty. It is included from vivid and ahead as you can se [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=php5-phpdbg&searchon=names).

So, how can I install phpdbg in Ubuntu 14.04?

Answer (score 0):

Try this steps :

First, check that the universe repository is enabled by inspecting `/etc/apt/sources.list` with your favourite editor.

You will need to use `sudo` to ensure that you have permissions to edit the file.

If universe is not included then modify the file so that it does.

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid main universe
```

Run the update :

```
sudo apt-get update
```

You can now install the package by typing :

```
sudo apt-get install php5-phpdbg
```

[Source](http://installion.co.uk/ubuntu/vivid/universe/p/php5-phpdbg/install/index.html).

Comment: But will not this cause problems with the trusty repository?. I bet there is going to be problems mixing repositories from different releases of Ubuntu.